# Parent Child Relation using CTE Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a CTE script to be able to select employees under one specific employee and be able to include the parent in the list as well.

For example I have Employee 123 has three employees under him, 111, 222 and 333, I have a three view already created with the hierarchy, the user clicks on 123 and should be able to see information for 111, 222 and 333, I also want to include the information of 123 as well.

I should be able to get this information starting from any node down, my issue is to include the starting node as well.

Here is the code:

```
declare @Personnel AS TABLE
(
   child_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   parent_id INT 
);

INSERT INTO @Personnel(child_id, parent_id)
   SELECT 111, 123 UNION ALL
   SELECT 222, 123 UNION ALL
   SELECT 333, 123

;WITH ChildsCTE(child_id, parent_id) AS
   (
      SELECT child_id, parent_id
        FROM @Personnel
       WHERE parent_id = 123

       UNION ALL

      SELECT Curr.child_id, Curr.parent_id
        FROM ChildsCTE AS Prev
             INNER JOIN
             @Personnel AS Curr
             ON Curr.parent_id = Prev.child_id
   )
   SELECT C.child_id, C.parent_id
     FROM ChildsCTE AS C
```

I want to be able to retrieve:

```
child_id    parent_id
111         123
222         123
333         123
```

plus the parent in some way like this:

```
child_id    parent_id
111         123
222         123
333         123
123             123 (or NULL)
```

The parent is not the top level employee, could be any one and of course could also be the top level one.

Comment: The query seems to work fine. Could you please include the table data and the expected output?

Comment: It work fine, but I need to be able to include in the list of childs, the parent as well, like for example if I click the parent I want to go and bring all the emails related to the people under him included him. That's the goal

Comment: Could you please post the data?

Comment: Thank you for publishing the expected output. Please see the answer below. You simply have to start with child_id = 123 as the starting node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to start with **child_id = 123** as the starting node. Please see the [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74023/1).

```
;WITH ChildsCTE(child_id, parent_id) AS
   (
      SELECT child_id, parent_id
        FROM @Personnel
       WHERE child_id = 123

       UNION ALL

      SELECT Curr.child_id, Curr.parent_id
        FROM ChildsCTE AS Prev
             INNER JOIN
             @Personnel AS Curr
             ON Curr.parent_id = Prev.child_id
   )
   SELECT C.child_id, C.parent_id
     FROM ChildsCTE AS C;
```

If the parent_id (123)'s parent_id also will be the same, then, please use the following query. Both the child_id and the parent_id are used in the joins ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22f2e/4)).

```
;WITH ChildsCTE(child_id, parent_id) AS
   (
      SELECT child_id, parent_id
        FROM @Personnel
       WHERE child_id = 123 and parent_id = 123

       UNION ALL

      SELECT Curr.child_id, Curr.parent_id
        FROM ChildsCTE AS Prev
             INNER JOIN
             @Personnel AS Curr
             ON Curr.parent_id = Prev.child_id AND Curr.child_id <> Prev.parent_id
   )
   SELECT C.child_id, C.parent_id
     FROM ChildsCTE AS C;
```